# Android Studio - Android Gradle Plugin That Supports 33 (?)

Tags: android, gradle

It occured three days ago and couldn't find a solution yet.  When I tried to run an app on my phone I receive this eror : " Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android   Gradle plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

```
  Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
  allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
  targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
  minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
  on)."
```

I literally tried every kind of update but still couldn't figure it out.

[image]

I updated Git VSC plugin , compileSDKversion ,Android Gradle , crated  a new project , restarted Android Studio... None of them worked out.

Comment: Can you share your .gradle?